# Time complexity of a for or while loop

Tags: python, loops, time-complexity

The time complexity of a for loop with n as the input is O(n) from what I've understood till now but what about the code inside the loop?

```
while var in arr:
    arr.remove(var)
```

arr is a list with n elements and var can be a string or a number.

How do I know if I should multiply or add time complexities? Is the time complexity of the above code O(n**2) or O(n)?

```
for i in range(n):
    arr.remove(var)
    arr.remove(var1)
```

What would the time complexity be now? What should I add or multiply?

I tried learning about time complexity but couldn't understand how to deal with code having more than one time complexity.

Comment: The second code will crash (unless n=0). Is that really the code you want to ask about?

Comment: @KellyBundy it's just an example snippet for two operations. There's no such code

Comment: Would still be better to use a sensible example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the time complexity of the content inside the loop.

```py
for i in arr:  # O(n) 
    print(sum(arr) - i)  # O(n)
```

In this case, the `.pop(0)` is nested in the forloop, so you need to multiply the complexity to the forloop complexity: O(n) * O(n) > O(n*n) > O(n²).

```py
for i in arr:  # O(n) 
    print(sum(arr) - i)  # O(n)
    print(sum(arr) - i)  # O(n)
```

In this case, it's

```
O(n) * (O(n) + O(n))
O(n) * O(n+n)
O(n) * O(2n)
O(n) * O(n)
O(n*n)
O(n²)
```

See [When to add and when to multiply to find time complexity](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/100264) for more information about that.

For a while loop, it doesn't change anything: multiply content with the complexity of the while.

Comment: Hmm, none of your code snippets are any of theirs.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't want to multiply. In this case, the *result* is the same, but you are really summing a series of operations involving an every-shrinking value of `n`. (`sum(range(n)) == O(n**2)`)

Comment: @chepner To be more precise: `sum(range(n/2), n)` and `sum(range(n/3), n)`, respectively.

Comment: @chepner right, didn't noticed that, thanks, I'll change the example. Is it better?